# jQuery Ajax Request Gets no Reponse on IIS 7.5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, iis-7.5, iis-express

Sending jquery ajax request to ASP.NET 4.5.1 web:

```
var request = $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.ashx?' + ajaxMethod,
        dataType: 'json',
        responseType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        type: "POST",
        data: data
    });
```

When using IIS Express the server receives the ajax request.
When using IIS 7.5  the server does not receives the ajax request.
Notes:
There was no problem on my old PC with this web site. The problem started on a new PC.
No problem with .aspx pages.

Comment: Have you added the .json to MIME types?  Check handler mappings as well.

Comment: What are you monitoring that shows the request is not received? Is it not received, or just not processed?

Comment: When calling another ajax request that returns json string i get:<br/>
"Value does not fall within the expected range" exception in IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
The problem was permission to access SQL Server using trusted connection.
After changing the connection string to use User/Password connection it works.

Answer (score 0):

Better user Fiddler or Chrome DevToolbar to check what the request looks like and what is the exact response from the server.